# Order of assignments in a where clause during a select that makes a join between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, join

I got a doubt. Suppose I got this:

```
Invoice (Cod, CodCustomer)
Customer (Cod,Name)
```

and i want to select the Customer's name of an X invoice:

```
SELECT Customer.Name FROM Invoice,Customer WHERE Customer.Cod = CodCustomer AND Invoice.Cod = "X"
```

during an optimization, is there a difference if I do

```
Customer.Cod = CodCustomer
```

or

```
CodCustomer = Customer.Cod
```

?

Thanks :)

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference, if the query takes to long, consider creating a index on `Customer.Cod` and `Invoice.CodCustomer` and `Invoice.Cod`, if you not already did so.

Comment: @Francesco . . . If you are interested in such things, learn about `explain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But You can do the second AND before this.

```
SELECT Customer.Name FROM Invoice,Customer WHERE Invoice.Cod = "X" AND Customer.Cod = CodCustomer
```

This might improve your performance, if no of Invoices having `Cod` as 'x' is fewer.

Comment: . . Do you have any documentation or examples of where this occurs?  All my experience and all the references that I find say that the order of the `where` clauses does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
Invoice.CodCustomer = Customer.Cod
```

The order it's not really important since it's just a comparison and it's true all way round.

Otherwise you can use an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.Name 
FROM Customer a  
INNER JOIN Invoice b
ON a.Cod = b.CodCustomer 
AND b.Cod = 'X' --note single quotes, you used double wich are not correct
```